# How to extract <p> matching specific text considering it also has <b>?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I find a paragraph HTML element that has a bold element inside? The bold element changes. It can be Michal and then Luis.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = "<p>Hello<b>Michael</b></p>"
# it could be  "<p>Hello<b>Luis</b></p>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

testing = soup.find('p', text=re.compile(r"Hello"))
```

The testing variable returns None.

Consider that the html has tons of paragraphs I can't simply do a `soup.find_all("p")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Beautiful Soup 4.7.0+` you could go with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [`pseudo-classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) that comes with `Soup Sieve` as the official CSS *select*.

So you could simply chain the conditions to:

```
soup.select('p:has(b):-soup-contains("Hello")')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<p>Hello<b>Michael</b></p>
<p>some other p tags</p>
<p>some other p tags</p>
<p>Hello<b>Luis</b></p>
<p>some other p tags</p>
<p>some other p tags</p>
<p>Not matching<b>Luis</b></p>

'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('p:has(b):-soup-contains("Hello")')
```

##### Output

```
[<p>Hello<b>Michael</b></p>, <p>Hello<b>Luis</b></p>]
```